# store 0 as price in Cart codeigniter class

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart, extends

In my application, I have both free tickets and paid tickets in my products and user can add both free and paid tickets. Cart class won't be able to add the product if price given is 0. To add product in the cart if price is 0, I have to extend the Cart class but nothing is working out. Help appreciated.

```
<?php

    class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }



    function insert_item($items = array())
    {
        // Was any cart data passed? No? Bah...
        if ( ! is_array($items) OR count($items) == 0)
        {
            log_message('error', 'The insert method must be passed an array containing data.');
            return FALSE;
        }

        $save_cart = FALSE;
        if (isset($items['id']))
        {
            if (($rowid = $this->_insert_item($items)))
            {
                $save_cart = TRUE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($items as $val)
            {
                if (is_array($val) AND isset($val['id']))
                {
                    if ($this->_insert_item($val))
                    {
                        $save_cart = TRUE;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the cart data if the insert was successful
        if ($save_cart == TRUE)
        {
            $this->_save_cart();
            return isset($rowid) ? $rowid : TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    function _insert_item($items = array())
    {
        // Was any cart data passed? No? Bah...
        if ( ! is_array($items) OR count($items) == 0)
        {
            log_message('error', 'The insert method must be passed an array containing data.');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Does the $items array contain an id, quantity, price, and name?  These are required
        if ( ! isset($items['id']) OR ! isset($items['qty']) OR ! isset($items['price']) OR ! isset($items['name']))
        {
            log_message('error', 'The cart array must contain a product ID, quantity, price, and name.');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Prep the quantity. It can only be a number.  Duh...
        $items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9])/i', '', $items['qty']));
        // Trim any leading zeros
        $items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/(^[0]+)/i', '', $items['qty']));

        // If the quantity is zero or blank there's nothing for us to do
        if ( ! is_numeric($items['qty']) OR $items['qty'] == 0)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_id_rules."]+$/i", $items['id']))
        {
            log_message('error', 'Invalid product ID.  The product ID can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, and underscores');
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! preg_match("/^[".$this->product_name_rules."]+$/i", $items['name']))
        {
            log_message('error', 'An invalid name was submitted as the product name: '.$items['name'].' The name can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, and spaces');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Prep the price.  Remove anything that isn't a number or decimal point.
        $items['price'] = trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9\.])/i', '', $items['price']));

        // Is the price a valid number?
        if ( ! is_numeric($items['price']))
        {
            log_message('error', 'An invalid price was submitted for product ID: '.$items['id']);
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (isset($items['options']) AND count($items['options']) > 0)
        {
            $rowid = md5($items['id'].implode('', $items['options']));
        }
        else
        {
            $rowid = md5($items['id']);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Now that we have our unique "row ID", we'll add our cart items to the master array

        // let's unset this first, just to make sure our index contains only the data from this submission
        unset($this->_cart_contents[$rowid]);

        // Create a new index with our new row ID
        $this->_cart_contents[$rowid]['rowid'] = $rowid;

        // And add the new items to the cart array
        foreach ($items as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->_cart_contents[$rowid][$key] = $val;
        }

        // Woot!
        return $rowid;
    }
```

Comment: Would converting the 0 to number format solve your problem?

Comment: How can I convert 0 to number format? Help appreciated.

Comment: number_format($priceVariable, 2, '.', ',')

Comment: http://in1.php.net/number_format

Comment: It converts value 0 to .00. It also trims the leading 0. No luck.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure it would work so didn't rush into adding it as an answer. Other guy fell into the trap of copying :P

Answer (score 1):

You can comment this out line 198

```
$items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/(^[0]+)/i', '', $items['qty']));
```

Answer (score 0):

change the format of number [number_format()](https://www.php.net/number_format)

```
number_format($variable, 2, '.', ',')
```

also why you using preg_match to check numeric for price there is many function in php for this to check number like try

```
is_numeric($items['price'])
```

Comment: It converts value 0 to .00. It also trims the leading 0. No luck.

Comment: try echo number_format(0, 2, '.', ','); //0.00 may be you have something wrong please debug line by line for price

Comment: Basically cart functionality converts 0.00 to .00. I then, take .00 and stores it in database. But at the time of reading or updating, it doesn't enter the new values. There is some problem.

Comment: what is datatype of field in db for price is float?

Comment: Actually I am serializing the product details array and storing it in a column.

Comment: may be your serialize problem try to insert in single column(float) is this ok? then check serialize

Comment: it's not serializing problem. It's a ".00" problem.